# How to delete a column based on a condition in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have following data frame :

```
user_id product_1 product_2 product_3 product_3 product_4
1          1        2           0        4       5
2          0        0           0        1       3
3          4        6           0        8       4
4          2        4           0        2       2
5          4        4           0        0       0
```

generally how can i exclude columns where sum(column)==0 , and how can i do it using dplyr package?

Comment: Take a look at `?colSums`. Also, do you also want to remove a column with values like `c(-1,0,0,0,1)` or only if they are all 0?

Comment: @docendodiscimus can i include colSums in dyplr::filter?

Comment: If you want to select columns, you will have to use `select` (since `filter` is used to choose rows). And yes, you can use `colSums` inside `select`, though you might need to wrap it in `which` to produce an integer vector of the column indices

Comment: docendo means something like `mtcars %>% select(which(colSums(.) > 90))`

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have to use `dplyr` package, you can also do this in `base`:

```
df[colSums(df) != 0]

  user_id product_1 product_2 product_3.1 product_4
1       1         1         2           4         5
2       2         0         0           1         3
3       3         4         6           8         4
4       4         2         4           2         2
5       5         4         4           0         0
```

Comment: Or use `df[sapply(df, sum) != 0]`.